# what is serialization, can't i do it for methods or varibales in a class

Tags: asp.net

Could some body explain me why we do serialization an what is profit of this ?

can we put serialize word on method or not, like in the following program on complete class the serialization is done can i do it on a method or a variable

```
Serializable]
public class StudentInfo
{
    //Default Constructor
    public StudentInfo()
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create object of student Class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="intRoll">Int RollNumber</param>
    /// <param name="strName">String Name</param>
    public StudentInfo(int intRoll, string strName)
    {
        this.Roll = intRoll;
        this.Name = strName;
    }

    private int intRoll;
    private string strName;
    public int Roll
    {
        get
        {
            return intRoll;
        }
        set
        {
            intRoll = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return strName;
        }
        set
        {
            strName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little background research to ask a better question goes a long way...

Answer (score 1):

You need serialization to transform data to XML or Json or for communication with a web service or with AJAX, or for saving or retrieving data in a ASP.NET session or for .NET remoting, which is why you can mark methods as serializable, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Serialization is the process of converting object into byte stream which is useful to transport object(i.e remoting) persisting object(i.e files database)
```

For details you can look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Akhtar: what about xml serialization as by MSDN "Serialization is the process of converting an object into a form that can be readily transported"

Comment: @Azhar, yes, this is also ture.